# For an Angularjs single page app, two tabs show the same favicon. I need different favicons in both the tabs

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a single page angularjs application. In the main page i have a favicon set like below

```
    <link href="img/favicon-flag.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

On the click of an edit link in this main page, a new tab opens and i have the below code to dynamically add a new fav icon. The "url" parameter has the link to the new FAVICON.

```
    var setFavicon = function (url) {
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']");
    if (link.href.indexOf(url) === -1)
    {
        link.type = "image/x-icon";
        link.rel = "icon";
        link.href = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
    };
```

When the above code runs. Both the tabs in the browser get updated to the new favicon.I need oly the edit tab with the new favicon. I am not sure why IE11 is behaving this way. Same code works perfectly fine in Chrome. Can you please let me know why this is happening.

I tries clearing cache and browser history and restrted IE11. Still no luck. Please help me out.